# Counting selected elements with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

Using Javascript and the d3 library I have made a map of the constituencies in the UK (excluding NI), and have added the ability to select the colour of each constituency. I am now hoping to count the number of constituencies of each colour and display them on a bar chart. The constituencies data comes from a topojson file.

Could someone advise me on how to do this. Many thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
        /* define style for map */
        .constituency {
            fill:   black;
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 0.25px;
        }
//      .constituency.W28 { fill: red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script>

// create map
var width = 700,
height = 1000;


var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    //.center([0, 55.4])
    .center([3, 54])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(4000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    //.translate(200,200)
    ;

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', redraw))
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("dblclick.zoom", null)
     ;
function redraw() {
    svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate + ') scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')');
}
var currentColor = "black";
var toggleColor = (function(){
  var i=0;
  var Colors = ["black","rgba(5, 117, 201, 1)", "rgba(237, 30, 14, 1)", "rgba(254, 131, 0, 1)", "rgba(235, 195, 28, 1)", "rgba(113, 47, 135, 1)", "rgba(120, 195, 30, 1)","rgba(78, 159, 47, 1)"];


  return function(){
    i=0;
   if(currentColor != "rgba(120, 195, 30, 1)"){
        while(currentColor != Colors[i]){
                i++;
                }
        currentColor = Colors[i+1];
         }
    else{
        currentColor  = "black";
        }

//       currentColor = currentColor == "rgba(5, 117, 201, 1)" ? "rgba(237, 30, 14, 1)" : "rgba(5, 117, 201, 1)";
        d3.select(this).style("fill", currentColor);
    }
})();

d3.json("constituencies.topo.json", function(error, topology) {
    // create a polygon for every constituency
    svg.selectAll(".constituency")
        // retrieve the features so that we can access the id
        .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.constituencies).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "constituency " + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", "black")
       .on("click", toggleColor)
});

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the constituencies that you've created with topojson:

```
var constituencies = topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.constituencies).features
svg.selectAll(".constituency")
    .data(constituencies).features)
    .enter().append("path")
...
```

Then tweak the click function to update both the DOM and the constituency bound to that element with current color:

```
return function(d){
  i = 0;
  if (currentColor != "rgba(120, 195, 30, 1)"){
    while(currentColor != Colors[i]) i++;
    currentColor = Colors[i+1];
  } else{ currentColor  = "black"; }

  d3.select(this).style("fill", currentColor);
  d.currentColor = currentColor; // save currentColor
}
```

Now you can group constituencies by color and use that information for bar chart:

```
 var byColor = d3.nest().key(d => d.currentColor).entries(constituencies)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Adam, I incidentally worked it out the same way, but thanks for the help.  Could I kindly ask you to have a look at my other question a continuation of this code where i have bar a html bar chart with the an array of all the coloured constituencies however it doesn't seem to redraw after selecting colours

Comment: Make sure that you're actually attaching the updated data to the bars. Either remove all the existing bars and add them again with .data(byColor).enter() or use selection.merge

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218